# Matrix modular inverse in python

Tags: python, numpy, encryption

I try to make Hill cipher algorithm using python and numpy. I did encryption without any problems. But I have some troubles with the decryption.
According to the Wiki I should get something like that:
[matrixes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ122.png)

It's not hard to do a simple inverse using numpy like`np.linalg.inv(keyMatrix)` but I can't do it modular by 26.
P.S 26 is the length of the alphabet

Comment: See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: You can do it in sagemath fairly easily

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that my problem can be solved using sympy package which is already installed in Anaconda. So, i only have to do this:

```
from sympy import Matrix
A = Matrix(keyMatrix) # keyMatrix is your basic matrix ndrarray format
A = A.inv_mod(26) #or any modulo you want
```