# I am doing a hill cipher encryption and decryption program, the encryption is good but I can't determine what's wrong with the decryption

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption

This is the entire code

```
    def hill_encrypt(plain_text, key_cipher):
        n = len(key_cipher)
     plain_text = plain_text.upper().replace(' ', '')
     if len(plain_text) % n != 0: 
     plain_text += 'X' * (n - len(plain_text) % n)
     encrypted_text = ''
     for i in range(0, len(plain_text), n):
            block = plain_text[i:i+n]
     block_nums = np.array([char_to_num(c) for c in block])
     encrypted_block_nums = np.dot(key_cipher, block_nums) % 26
            
    encrypted_block = ''.join([num_to_char(num) for num in encrypted_block_nums])
    encrypted_text += encrypted_block
    return encrypted_text
    
    name = 'HELLO' key = [[2, 4, 8], [14, 23, 14], [10, 20, 17]] 
    name_encrypted = hill_encrypt(name, key) 
    print('Encrypted Text:', name_encrypted)
    
    inverse_key = np.linalg.inv(key) print(inverse_key)
    
    def hill_decrypt(key_cipher, K_inv): n = len(K_inv)
    
    plain_text = ''
    
    for i in range(0, len(key_cipher), n):
        block = key_cipher[i:i+n]
        block_nums = np.array([char_to_num(c) for c in block])
        decrypted_block_nums = np.dot(K_inv, block_nums) % 26
        decrypted_block_nums = decrypted_block_nums.astype(int)
        decrypted_block = ''.join([num_to_char(num) for num in decrypted_block_nums])
        plain_text += decrypted_block
    
    return plain_text
    
    key_inv = inverse_key 
    name_decrypted = hill_decrypt(name_encrypted, key_inv) 
    print('Decrypted Text:', name_decrypted)
```

```
'''Inverse Key from the Inverse key calculation: 
[[ 4.82608696e-01  4.00000000e-01 -5.56521739e-01] 
[-4.26086957e-01 -2.00000000e-01  3.65217391e-01] 
[ 2.17391304e-01 -1.36191955e-17 -4.34782609e-02]]'''
```

'HELLO' encrypted returns as follows

```
Encrypted Text: OGZCSB
```

But the decrypted version returns as a further encryption of the already encrypted string text

```
Decrypted Text: VBBHVA
```

I have tried a longer method of iterating over the blocks using a for loop to go over each element at each row and column but the return is the same. I think the error is in the way I iterate but I can't seem to find.

Comment: The indentation in the code snippet is all messed up. Please repost correctly.

Comment: See my answer below.  But I have found once source that says the determinant of a Hill matrix must not be a multiple of 2 or 13 for it to have an inverse mod 26.  np.linalg.det(key_cipher) = 230, so your matrix can't be used.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `np.linalg.key` to get the decryption key of a Hill cipher.  Hill ciphers work in mod 26 arithmetic.  The decryption matrix is the matrix that consists entirely of integers, than when multiplied by the encryption matrix gives the identity matrix.

I do not know of any easy way of calculating this in Python.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58644922/4996248) to a similar question suggests that `sympy` has the ability to calculate modular matrix inverses.

Comment: @JohnColeman    I had seen that and quickly glanced through the sympy docs, but didn't see anything.

Comment: I added a note above.  But I'll repeat hear.  The determinant of the matrix can't be a multiple of 2 or 13 for it to have an inverse mod 26.  The matrix above's determinant is even, so it won't work.

Comment: Good point about the determinant. It seems that OP was trying to code Hill's cipher without understanding how it actually works.

Comment: I didn't know my matrix couldn't be a multiple of both those numbers, thank you

Comment: This paper http://www.math.utah.edu/~gustafso/s2018/2270/labs/lab5-hillcipher.pdf gives an example of calculating the inverse of a matrix mod 26.  The fact that 26 is not prime complicates things.